# allow only one ip and block others by using cmd in windows firewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, windows-command-prompt, rules

I want to allow one IP address that can connect to internet (whitelist) and block others' connections through internet using Windows Firewall on Server 2008 using command prompt.

1. Is it possible to only allow given IP address (example 192.168.1.5)
   and block all IP address by using cmd?
2. And how do i disable all
   allow rules by using cmd?

Comment: Allow only one IP address as what or to do what?

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Comment: sorry about that. i want to allow one IP address that can connect to internet(whitelist) and block others connections through internet.

Comment: Are you using the box that you are trying to configure the Windows Firewall on as a proxy of some sort or do you have another proxy server?

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted for all the netsh advfirewall commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `netsh advfirewall` ([commands listed here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx)) to administer Windows Firewall via command line.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please mark it as answer.